# Как из адаптера передать данные в Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть Activity, в котором ListView. Для этого ListView есть адаптер. Мне нужно каким-то образом при клике (`viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`) из адаптера, передать в Activity что-то и получить оттуда это значение.

Сколько гуглил, так и не нашёл решение. Там в основном решения с переходом в само Activity и Extra-параметры, что мне не подходит. Мне НЕ нужно открывать Activity при клике, мне нужно лишь как-то передать туда данные и получить их оттуда.

**Код адаптера:**

```html
public class WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj> items;

    int selected_position = 0;

    WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder;

        viewHolder = new WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter.ViewHolder();

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_withdraw_payments_systems, parent, false);
        }

        WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj currentItem = (WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj) getItem(position);

        viewHolder.item = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);

        viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // как-то тут передать что-то в Activity
            }
        });

        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageResource(currentItem.getItemIcon());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(currentItem.getItemTitle());
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description)).setText(currentItem.getItemDescription());
        ((EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id)).setText(currentItem.getItemId());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout item;
        RadioButton payment_system_rb;
    }
}
```

**Код ListView:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:background="@drawable/style_items_withdraw_payments_systems"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/description"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="#808080"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/payment_system_rb"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Реализуете клик через интерфейс, и саму реализацию нажатия делаете во фрагменте/активности. Там где обычно открывают другое активити у вас приходит как правило Item.getAdapterPosition то есть элемент при нажатой позиции. Далее делаете с ним все что захотите

Comment: А ещё рекомендую забить на ListView и использовать RecyclerView.

Answer (score 4):

Создаете интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onClick(data: YourData);
}
```

Реализуете его в Activity/Fragment:

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity() implements OnItemClickListener {

    // some code

    private WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter adapter = new WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter(this, ваш список, this);
    // первый аргумент вы передаете туда как контекст this (к примеру если тут будет фрагмент то вы передадите requaireCotext()), третий как класс который реализует OnItemClickListener - this

    @Override
    public void onClick(data: YourData) {
        // обрабатываете здесь ваши данные
    }
}
```

Кладете в ваш адаптер в конструктор (или отдельный метод setListener())

```
public class WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj> items;
    private OnItemClickListener listener; 

    int selected_position = 0;

    WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WithdrawPaymentsSystemsObj> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // some code

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // some code

        viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onClick(data); // вот сюда вы и должны передать ваши данные
            }
        });

        // some code

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте котлин и сделайте следующим образом

```
class WithdrawPaymentsSystemsAdapter : BaseAdapter {

var onItemClick: ((Model) -> (Unit))? = null  // Model - тип ваших данных

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup) {
        // some code

        viewHolder.item.setOnClickListener {
             onItemClick?.invoke(data[position]) // оправьте ваши данные            
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

В вашей активити вызовите следующее

```
adapter.onItemClick = { model ->
    // можете использовать ваши данные как model, например

    send(model.name)
}
```