# Как передать данные из адаптера RecycleView в активити

Tags: android, kotlin

Есть список Recycleview, в нем EditText. Нужно чтобы при изменении текста в EditText перезаписывалось в db.
Само изменение текста ловлю в адаптере через doAfterTextChanged и хочу его отправить в MainActivity.

```
edText.doAfterTextChanged {
                val txt = it.toString()}
```

Чтобы там уже вызвать функцию с новым текстом для обновления Item в базе. Т.к. хз почему нельзя сделать это в адаптере.

```
suspend fun updateItem (content: String, id: Int, time: String) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val selection = BaseColumns._ID + "=$id"
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MyDbNameClass.COLUMN_NAME_CONTENT, content)
        put(MyDbNameClass.COLUMN_NAME_TIME, time)
    }
    db?.update(MyDbNameClass.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, null)
}
```

Пробовал через Intent, но необходимо перезапускать Активити. Через Boundle пробовал, но тоже не получилось. Других вариантов не знаю еще и найти не получается, поэтому прошу помощи знающих. Только начинаю познавать эти дебри, соответственно, прошу дать развернутый ответ, по возможности.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1164268/11515

Comment: Обычно текст редактируют в специальной форме а не в Recycle View, но если вы выбрали такой вариант, то как вариант можно активность передать в конструктор адаптера.